# Display GMAP direction with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display a GMAP Direction in rails with my source and destination (with latitude and longitude). so How can I do this ?

I am using Rails 3.2.x

If possible then please give me a example for this.

Thank In Advance.

Comment: there is an example here: http://apneadiving.github.io/

Comment: this is example, I need a code for that

Comment: click `code` tab, presents code, magic

Comment: that's not work, I copied and Paste in my side

Comment: actually it relies on the gmaps4rails gem, you'd have to install it first...

Comment: yes, that already installed